# How exchange data between web and console java applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have question how can I realize exchanging of data between Web Java Application (servlets) running on tomcat and standalone console java application? Everything is hosted on one machine.

Problem is following: I need to click on some button on web page, then servlet is executed. Next from servlet I need to ask about data which are stored in standalone application. Using database and file storage is forbidden.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why is it "forbidden"? What does that mean exactly, how does the standalone app store it's data if not in a database or the file system?

Comment: can you use java rmi

Answer (score 0):

Question seems unclear, but let me give an answer under my assumptions...

You are using webapp deployed on tomcat, and clicking on a button on this web-application, then on same server you have one another java console application running in parallel, so your web application click should get and read data from this console application, and such limitations like you can't use memory types : databases or files am i right ?

If so, please kindly know that "file" or "database" is not last memory types in the world, there are others as well. For example, java sockets can help you in the way that you can implement messaging on specific port between standalone application and web application, client/server based , which your server is "standalone console app" that serves data for client "java web application" deployed on tomcat.

Please check examples :

https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/